# SQL Server Dynamic Pivot in UDF that returns table

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot, user-defined-functions

I have the following query that uses dynamic pivot to return some data in the format I am expecting:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMPDOCS (DOCID INT, NAME VARCHAR(30))
CREATE TABLE PROVIDERIDS (ID INT, PARENTID INT, QUALIFIER VARCHAR(20), IDENTIFIER VARCHAR(30))
INSERT INTO TEMPDOCS VALUES (1, 'ROGER, HARPER')
INSERT INTO TEMPDOCS VALUES (2, 'WALTZ, HEALY')

INSERT INTO PROVIDERIDS VALUES (1, 1, 'DEA', 'D12345')
INSERT INTO PROVIDERIDS VALUES (2, 1, 'NPI', 'N12345')
INSERT INTO PROVIDERIDS VALUES (3, 1, 'LIC', 'L12345')
INSERT INTO PROVIDERIDS VALUES (4, 2, 'NPI', 'N23456')
INSERT INTO PROVIDERIDS VALUES (5, 2, 'REG', 'R23456')

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @id as int = 1;

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(QUALIFIER) 
            FROM PROVIDERIDS
            LEFT OUTER JOIN TEMPDOCS on TEMPDOCS.DOCID = PROVIDERIDS.PARENTID
            WHERE DOCID = @id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT DOCID, NAME, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select TEMPDOCS.DOCID, TEMPDOCS.NAME, PROVIDERIDS.QUALIFIER, PROVIDERIDS.IDENTIFIER FROM TEMPDOCS
                LEFT OUTER JOIN PROVIDERIDS ON PROVIDERIDS.PARENTID=TEMPDOCS.DOCID
                WHERE TEMPDOCS.DOCID = ' + CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(30)) + '
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                MAX(IDENTIFIER)
                FOR QUALIFIER IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

I want to convert this code into an user defined function that return a TABLE. I tried doing it but not able to make it work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION udfGetProviderIds (@DoctorId INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @id as int = 1;

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(QUALIFIER) 
            FROM PROVIDERIDS
            LEFT OUTER JOIN TEMPDOCS on TEMPDOCS.DOCID = PROVIDERIDS.PARENTID
            WHERE DOCID = @id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT DOCID, NAME, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select TEMPDOCS.DOCID, TEMPDOCS.NAME, PROVIDERIDS.QUALIFIER, PROVIDERIDS.IDENTIFIER FROM TEMPDOCS
                LEFT OUTER JOIN PROVIDERIDS ON PROVIDERIDS.PARENTID=TEMPDOCS.DOCID
                WHERE TEMPDOCS.DOCID = ' + CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(30)) + '
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                MAX(IDENTIFIER)
                FOR QUALIFIER IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


    RETURN execute(@query)  
END
```

I am getting following error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 31, Procedure udfGetProviderIds, Line 32
Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN'.
```

Is there a way to make this work without declaring the TABLE and the structure in the returns clause? Or, is there a better way of creating UDF with dynamic Pivot?

Comment: Can't do dynamic SQL in a UDF, sorry. That's a hard limit.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. What should be my approach then? Any suggestion?

Comment: Yeah, find other ways to share the data than a table-valued function. [Erland Sommarskog has some ideas](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) but I did not read the entire question nor do I understand your requirements. I just wanted you to be aware that dynamic SQL is not possible within a function ([well, unless you can get this ill-advised hack to work for your situation](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12585/invalid-use-of-a-side-effecting-operator-insert-within-a-function-multiple-i/12586#12586) - also involving Erland, funnily enough).

Comment: :-) thanks. Let me go through the links and see if I can make this work for me. But thanks for the information. I was thinking that my return statement is wrong the whole time. It never occurred that dynamic sql can be a problem in UDFs.

Answer (score 0):

Like Aaron has explained you cannot use dynamic sql in UDF but I can think of a way around just put all of your functions definition in a store procedure and you can get the results returned from stored proc into a temp table something like this

```
CREATE PROC usp_GetProviderIds 
@DoctorId INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @id as int = 1;

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(QUALIFIER) 
            FROM PROVIDERIDS
            LEFT OUTER JOIN TEMPDOCS on TEMPDOCS.DOCID = PROVIDERIDS.PARENTID
            WHERE DOCID = @id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT DOCID, NAME, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select TEMPDOCS.DOCID, TEMPDOCS.NAME, PROVIDERIDS.QUALIFIER, PROVIDERIDS.IDENTIFIER FROM TEMPDOCS
                LEFT OUTER JOIN PROVIDERIDS ON PROVIDERIDS.PARENTID=TEMPDOCS.DOCID
                WHERE TEMPDOCS.DOCID = ' + CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(30)) + '
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                MAX(IDENTIFIER)
                FOR QUALIFIER IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


    EXECUTE sp_Executesql @query  
END
```

And then you can get the returned result set into a temp table by doing the following

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (Col1, Col2.....)
INSERT INTO #TempTable
EXEC usp_GetProviderIds @DoctorId
```

Comment: Hmm, but whole purpose was that I won't know the number of columns.. it is dynamically coming from the other table.. is there a way to create temp table on the fly with EXEC like how we can do with "select into table".